# What is the "best-practice" approach to "switch between pages" in an Electron app?

Tags: html, node.js, electron, ipc

Spontaneously, I see two options to "switch between pages" in an Electron app:

Option 1:
Usage of hyperlink like `<a href="...">...</a>` in the html-file currently being displayed in the renderer process.

Option 2:
Send request from renderer process to main process using IPC and have main process load another html-file in the window of the renderer process that has sent the IPC message.

```
ipcRenderer.send('switch-html-page', idOfNewPage);
```

What is the "best-practice" approach? Are these options valid? Are there better solutions? Thank you very much for your insights!

Answer (score 0):

I worked with electron.
Option2 is  an expensive and a time consuming process.But option is a light weight process.
Option1 will be the right choice.Or else use tabs from bootstrap or material ui
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navs-tabs/